# Count substrings in SQL (in Digital Metaphors' ReportBuilder)

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, reportbuilder

I'm trying to create a report in ReportBuilder (Digital Metaphors, not Microsoft) and I'm having trouble getting the SQL to do what I want.

I have one table with a field `building`:

```
| building   |
+------------+
| WhiteHouse |
| TajMahal   |
```

and another table with a field `locations`:

```
| id | locations                                                       |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | WhiteHouse:RoseGarden,WhiteHouse:MapRoom,TajMahal:MainSanctuary |
| 2  | TajMahal:NorthGarden,WhiteHouse:GreenRoom                       |
```

I would like to create a table showing how many times each building is used in `locations`, like so:

```
| building   | count |
+------------+-------+
| WhiteHouse | 3     |
| TajMahal   | 2     |
```

The characters `:` and `,` are never used in building or room names. Even a quick-and-dirty solution that assumes that building names never appear in room names would be good enough for me.

Of course this would be easy to do in just about any sane programming language (total over something like `/\bWhiteHouse:/`); the trick will be getting RB to do it. Suggestions for workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Personally, I would separate `locations` field in 2 fields (one named `building` and the other one named `room`). In each record I would store one `building` and one `room` only. Then I would use a simple `count` and a `group by`

Comment: @Fabrizio Yes, if the data was stored that way my task would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to split locations string into pieces using the "," and ":" characters as seperators as follows in SQL Server with the help of a custom [sql split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx)

```
select 
    p2.val,
    count(p2.val)
from locations l
cross apply dbo.split(l.locations,',') p1
cross apply dbo.split(p1.val,':') p2
inner join building b
    on b.building = p2.val
group by p2.val
```

I'm not sure there is a similar one in mysql, if so please check following solution as a template

Comment: This is about MySQL.

Comment: I have found a split function here https://github.com/KRSatpute/mysql_csv_parser/blob/master/sp_mysql_csv_parser.sql for mysql, may be it helps

Comment: Maybe, I cannot say, sorry. For the sake of my psychic health I'm not a fan of MySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, probably not the fastest, but certainly easier solution.

```
SELECT t1.building,
       ( SELECT SUM( ROUND( (LENGTH(t2.locations)  
                             - LENGTH(REPLACE(t2.locations, concat(t1.building, ':'), '')) 
                            ) / (LENGTH(t1.building) + 1)  
                          )
                   )
         FROM table2 AS t2  
       ) as count
FROM table1 as t1
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36bfc2/10)